# Why are Visual Studio's Dark Mode settings 'shared' between VS versions

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

I have both Visual Studio 2019 and Visual Studio 2022 installed on a Windows 10 machine.

If I changed the VS2022's Options/Environment settings to 'Dark Mode', BOTH the VS2022 and the VS2019 run in Dark Mode.

If the settings for each app are independent of each other, shouldn't I be able to have 2022 in Dark Mode and 2021 in Light Mode?

Is there a way to 'separate' 2022 and 2019 from sharing this setting?

I have checked and I do NOT have them using a shared settings file on the machine (i.e., they are using different locations for "Options/Import and Export Settings/..Save my settings to this file:".

Comment: Just guess, really, but do you have your settings "synchronized across devices" in Options->Environment->Accounts?

Comment: No, I do not have "synchronized across devices" checked. As soon as I changed the 'dark mode' setting in either running 2019 or 2022 instance, both instances change modes.